# How to change endpoint reference address dynamically?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, endpoint

I'm trying to change the endpoint of the SOAP request at runtime. Because, same SOAP client would be used to request from different server (but API remain same). And, I tried following code

```
 BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)repService.getPort (serviceInterface);
 bp.getRequestContext ().put (BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                               "http://" + sHost + "/xxxxyu/somepath?SoapImpl=" + serviceName);
```

It does change the endpoint property in request context map. But, when I call the method using this service it is still hitting older endpoint. Also, when I wrote below line of code before and after change the endpoint property. I see in both output I'm getting older url not the new endpoint url.

```
System.out.println ( bp.getEndpointReference ());
```

I'm totally clueless on what to do and thinking if it is possible ? Let me know, if I missed to add any details.